# Bigger HTTPS size

Tags: apache, ssl

On apache access log,  I find out that https return bigger size than http

```
210.10.0.156 - - [29/Apr/2019:12:22:46 +0800] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 5837 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
```

If you can see it is 5837 bytes where is for http less than 1000 bytes

my robots.txt content is only

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is this a normal things?

When i tried to do same thing on other server with cpanel installed, the size is much more lower, im not sure what configuration i missed, any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly normal.

Your website may not be configured for HTTP, which will redirect people to HTTPS with a 301 or 302 rule, meaning all they see when they access your site through HTTP is a redirect page, which is usually smaller than the regular webpage which they were expecting.

You can go to your website with http:// or https:// at the start of the URL and see if it looks any different.

Comment: But when i try to curl to other server (with cpanel installed), it is lower, do you know what is the configuration that i missed?

Comment: It depends what the data returning comes back as. Try and download the result then look at it. What are the differences between the two files?

Comment: The content is only 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /